# How to remotely send keyboard events to embedded Qt Quick Application?

Tags: linux, qt, keyboard, embedded, stdio

I have an embedded Linux 3.10.17 system running a Qt Quick 5.2.1 application. It has a graphical UI that can be controlled by plugging in a USB keyboard. What I would like to do is to control the application remotely via a remote desktop connection to a Windows PC sitting next to the embedded system. Currently any STDIO is not sent in as keyboard events to the Qt application. Three ideas came to mind

1. Modify Qt application to take in STDIO data so it acts on those events. I thought this would be a common thing to do, but so far my searches has not yielded any good solutions.
2. Create a Linux kernel driver that sends any keycodes received through a char device write (pipe) through the input subsystem. Something like this should be available I'd think...
3. Buy some form device that plugs into the embedded system via USB and connects to the PC via USB, RS232 or Ethernet.

I'm not sure which path offers the least resistance. Any expert advice on this would be appreciated

Thanks,

Otto

Comment: Btw, we use a webcam to view the Qt Application screen

Comment: If you can use Ethernet, you can use a udp socket and send all you want on that opened door.

Comment: Sure, but how to I pipe that into the kernels input system to trigger the events on the UI ?